# Using iotedgehubdev generated iothub modules don't run locally due to "repository name must be lowercase"

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to run a iothub module project generated using the plugin iotedgehubdev for visual studio code.

The generated debug template is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema-template": "4.0.0",
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.4",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {}
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "5671/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "5671"
                      }
                    ],
                    "8883/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                      }
                    ],
                    "443/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "443"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "ModBusModule": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.ModBusModule.debug}",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          },
          "SimulatedTemperatureSensor": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.4",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.4",
        "routes": {
          "ModBusModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/ModBusModule/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
          "sensorToModBusModule": "FROM /messages/modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/ModBusModule/inputs/input1\")"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
PS C:\projects\*redacted*\*redacted*\iot-edge-module\*redacted*> & "c:\Users\*redacted*\.vscode\extensions\vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-edge-1.25.11\iotedgehubdev\0.14.18\iotedgehubdev" start -d "c:\projects\*redacted*\*redacted*\iot-edge-module\*redacted*\config\deployment.debug.amd64.json" -v
edgeHub image version is ignored in solution mode.
Network azure-iot-edge-dev is external, skipping
Pulling edgeHubDev ... done
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

ERROR: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
ERROR: Error while executing command: docker-compose -f C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Local\.iotedgehubdev\data\data\docker-compose.yml up. Command '['docker-compose', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\*redacted*\\AppData\\Local\\.iotedgehubdev\\data\\data\\docker-compose.yml', 'up']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I however can't seem to find what exactly is causing this error.

- I've tried it with ModBusModule spelled all lower case but this did not resolve the issue. I've also tried with the image path specified as **"${MODULES<../ModBusModule.debug>}"**, **"${MODULES<../ModBusModule>}"**, **"${MODULDIR<../ModBusModule.debug>}"**, **"${MODULDIR<../ModBusModule>}"**.
- I've also tried using a hosted Azure container register.

But these things did not resolve the issue I'm having.
Does anyone have any idea as to what this issue might be? Obvious it's something repository name related but I don't know what part or where **MODULES** gets set by iotedgehubdev.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please follow this [git](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-modbus) for Azure IoT Edge Modbus Module

Comment: That I'm trying to make a ModBus module has nothing to do with that a default generated project doesn't run.

Comment: Please check the ```iotedgeModbus/deployment.template.json```  file to configure your `template.json`

Comment: I've found that when building the IoTEdge solution the config does not get set correctly. This seems to be a bug with the vscode plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some debugging and allot of troubleshooting with different project types and old iotedge projects. I have found what was giving the issues.

When generating a new module for csharp the following files are missing and need to be added manually.

1. All the docker files for the module
2. module.json

Once these files are added in the output file the image will be set correctly and the docker-compose error will stop.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=csharp&pivots=iotedge-dev-ext) and [git](https://github.com/ReneHezser/SimulatedTemperatureSensor) to simulate a sample module of Edge using Visual Studio Code.

```java
 "SimulatedTemperatureSensor": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.4",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          },
          "SampleFunction": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.SampleFunction}",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

- For the Azure IoT Edge module with Modbus template ,  refer to this [git](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-modbus) .

```json
 " "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"PortBindings\":{\"8883/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"8883\"}],\"443/tcp\":[{\"HostPort\":\"443\"}]}}}"
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "modbus": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.iotedgeModbus.amd64}",
              "createOptions": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```